# IMAGE COMPARISON USING OPENCV code from poitr

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

HI i found this code to compare images

```
cv::Mat img1 = ...
cv::Mat img2 = ...
cv::Mat result = ...

int threshold = (double)(img1.rows * img1.cols) * 0.7; 

cv::compare(img1 , img2  , result , cv::CMP_EQ );
int similarPixels  = countNonZero(result);

if ( similarPixels  > threshold ) {
   cout << "similar" << endl;
}
```

but since i m new to OPENCV i dont know what are the values for " cv::Mat img1=..."
please help me out and tried out the code with the image path as value but its giving an error

Answer (score 0):

```
void compare(const MatND& src1, const MatND& src2, MatND& dst, int cmpop)
```

compare function takes 4 parametres and this are ;

```
•src1 – The first source array
•src2 – The second source array; must have the same size and same type as src1
•value – The scalar value to compare each array element with
•dst – The destination array; will have the same size as src1 and type= CV_8UC1
```

And as i understand this image has some `fiducial points` like coordinate system ( `X / Y )`

such as ;

```
1 45 123
2 56 164
3 64 147
```

and with these points are storing in array and then it send arrays to compare function in order to find matchers .

If you want to work with image comparasion my advise is you can search `feret database` which is free to use for research.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [imread](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#Mat%20imread%28const%20string&%20filename,%20int%20flags%29) to load an image to `cv::Mat img1`, e.g.

```
cv::Mat img1 = imread("c:\\test.bmp");    // To load an RGB image
```